# beamer: include author names + affiliations (different for different authors) + author pictures

Tags: beamer, titles, includegraphics

I wish to have a title page that has a title, date, author names, affiliations (they are not all the same), and a picture of each author (except me, the presenter) -- so, four pictures. How can I achieve these? I have the following MWE that satisfies all but the pictures requirement.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage{collcell} %pdflatex.exe hangs without this one
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio! 

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}
\title{My title: \\
and here is the subtitle}
\date{today's date}
\author{A1\inst{1}, A2\inst{2}, A3\inst{3}, A4\inst{2}, and A5\inst{1}}
\institute{\inst{1} fancy university 1 \and \inst{2} not-so-fancy university 2 \and \inst{3} dream-place-to-work-at}%\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=myblue}

%% start1
\begin{document}
  \titlepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps a better alternative I would like to try is: title, then author names (only) with superscripts for affiliation, then the affiliations, then all pictures in a row. Otherwise everything is too clumsy,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{rose} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
\usepackage{collcell} %pdflatex.exe hangs without this one
\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz} %for beautiful inline highlighted math. Thanks Claudio!

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\newcommand\fiteq[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \ifdim\wd\mybox>.85\textwidth\resizebox{.85\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \else\usebox{\mybox}\fi%
}
\title{My title: \\
and here is the subtitle}
\date{today's date}
\author{
A1\inst{1},  \parbox[t]{22mm}{\centering    A2\inst{2},  
                           \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-duck}}
             \parbox[t]{22mm}{\centering   A3\inst{3},
                           \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-duck}}
             \parbox[t]{22mm}{\centering   A4\inst{2},
                           \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-duck}}
             \parbox[t]{22mm}{\centering   A5\inst{1}
                           \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-image-duck}}
    }
\institute{\inst{1} fancy university 1 \and \inst{2} not-so-fancy university 2 \and \inst{3} dream-place-to-work-at}%\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=myblue}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Adendum:***

As you required in comment below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %pdflatex.exe hangs without this one

\title{My title: \\
and here is the subtitle}
\date{\today}
\author{\setkeys{Gin}{width=15mm}
A1\inst{1}  \\[2ex]
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{Short Name\inst{2}\hfill
               \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}}\hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{A. B. Name3\inst{3}\hfill
               \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}} \\[2ex]
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{Forename Lastname\inst{2}\hfill
               \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}}\hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{My name is Long\inst{1}\hfill
               \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}}
    }
\institute{\inst{1} fancy university 1 \and \inst{2} not-so-fancy university 2 \and \inst{3} dream-place-to-work-at}%\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=myblue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(in above MWE is removed all definitions and packages irrelevant to your problem)

**One more addendum:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{My title}
\subtitle{here is the subtitle}
\date{\today}
\author{
A1\inst{1}, Short Name\inst{2}, A. B. Name3\inst{3}, Forename Lastname\inst{2} and My name is Long\inst{1}
    }
\institute{\inst{1} fancy university 1, \inst{2} not-so-fancy university 2, \inst{3} dream-place-to-work-at}%\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=myblue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\vfill
\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width=15mm}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\hfil
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\hfil
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}\hfil
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hopefully is now enough examples how can you format title frame of your presentation.

Comment: This is great -- one request: the author names are quite long. Would it be possible to make the first name and last name for all authors (including the one without the picture stacked above each other)? Otherwise the names + pictures don't fit, and the names + pictures are not in a nice order and showing up at arbitrary places on the slide. (Also, in case it matters, the speaker (without the picture) is the fourth author).

Comment: I guess maybe it's okay if the author pictures are not all in one line, but it would be nice if they would at least be a bit ordered -- so, maybe the first three authors on one line, and the next two below? Or, maybe we can reduce the spacing between the pictures?

Comment: @lazulikid, see addendum.

Comment: Sorry, last request: would it be possible to instead have the pictures at the bottom of the title page all grouped together? (Sorry, I realized this wasn't working out as I was trying the images). So, at the very top, title; then, all author names with superscripts indicating affliaation; then, the affiliations; then a row with just pictures.

Comment: @lazulikid, after showed example of title page design, I hope that you should be able to define own stile of title frame if presented is not exactly such as you imagine.